# Angular 2 Router: multiple route parameters

Tags: angular

I want to have a route with that url

```
/collections/:collectionId/books/:bookId/:title
```

e.g.

```
/collections/10/books/456678/my-book.html
```

in my app-routing.module.ts file

```
{path: 'collections/:collectionId/books/:bookId/:title', component: BookDetailsComponent},
```

Is is possible without using nested router outlets?

I tried

```
this.router.navigate(['/collections',{collectionId: 10, bookId: 456678, title: "my-book.html"}]);
```

but got an error like

```
Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'collections;collectionId=10;bookId=456678;title=my-book.html'
```

if I pass the paramaters as an array instead,

```
this.router.navigate(['/collections', 10, 456678, "my-book.html"]);
```

I get

```
Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'collections/10/456678/my-book.html
```

I managed to achieve what I wanted using a 'books' child route under the 'collections' route, but I'd like to do it without nested routes.

Thanks

Comment: What exactly you pass as an array to `router.navigate`?

Comment: @Dimanoid : i edited my question to show more code

Comment: You missed 'books' as a part of the path

Comment: @Dimanoid: yes that was the problem, thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It should be

```
this.router.navigate(['/collections', '10', 'books', '456678', "my-book.html"]);
```

The quotes around the numbers are not necessary but I think it's good practice.

Comment: Thanks.  However, it only seems to work if I have a <router-outet> in the corresponding template, as otherwise I get the error Cannot find primary outlet to load 'BookDetailsComponent'

Comment: Thanks for the hint about the comma. Not sure what you mean with the router outlet. A router-outlet is always mandatory. If you think it shouldn't for your case then a Plunker with a reproduction would be great to investigate.

Comment: The code (this.router.navigate...) is in a CollectionComponent, whose template contains no router outlet. My router-outlet is in my AppComponent. I'll try to create a plunker

Comment: I agree that it shouldn't require a router-outlet in this case because you are using an absolute path (starting with `/`)