# How to pass more than one variable between angular routes

Tags: angular, angular-routing

Here is my scenario: I need to navigate to a details page from the master page for eg: /details:id, but need to pass an extra object `{prop1: value, prop2: value}`. This is a known object in master. I cannot use queryParam as I don't want to pass the object in the query string. I also cannot use `@Input/@Output`, and I don't need a `resolver` as I am not calling any services. I tried route.data or snapshot.data but nothing works when I get to the detail page.  Is there anything I can use in this scenario? Can you provide a code sample? Thanks!

```
  {
        path: 'create/:id',
        component: SettingsComponent,
        canDeactivate: [CanDeactivateGuard]
    }

this.router.navigate(['/settings/edit', result.id]);
```

Source:
https://angular.io/guide/router

Comment: Possible duplication https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41013785/angular-2-router-multiple-route-parameters

Comment: @Imran this above link is using the query string solution. I am looking for some sort of POST mechanism.

Comment: if you want something that is not appened to the url go for a [shared service](https://rahulrsingh09.github.io/AngularConcepts/faq)

Comment: Thanks. I am looking for a routing based solution if exists.